# Is it possible to bypass "file_exists()" (RFI, LFI)?

Tags: php, security

I've got the following piece of code in my web app:

```
$data = "dir/files/".$_GET['f'].".pdf";
```

A couple of lines down I got:

```
if(file_exists($data)){
    include($data);
```

Could an attacker bypass that to exploit an RFI on my system? Or is it LFI only?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to make it a proper self-contained question. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to sanitize the user input! Even if they could only get to PDF files your still not ensured that they are only getting to files that are located in the directory you're specifying.

Consider the input `../../../siteB/dir/files/secure`. With your current code instead of accessing `/var/www/siteA/dir/files/secure.pdf` they are accessing `/var/www/siteB/dir/files/secure.pdf`.

One method to help this is to get just the last bit of the inputted string (without any of the leading path parts).

```
$file = basename($_GET['f']);
```

This will convert `../../../siteB/dir/files/secure` into `secure`. This is obviously only a partial solution. Other tests such as what if they input a blank string or characters that you'd consider invalid.

Answer (score 0):

In the same directory :

test.php

```
    <?
       if(file_exists($page)){
          echo("Sorry the local page is protected");
       }else{
          include($page);
    }?>
```

file.txt

```
  Hello Word
```

Input:
    http://www.example.com/test.php?page=file.txt
Result:
Sorry the local page is protected

Input:
    http://www.example.com/test.php?page=./foo/../file.txt
Result:
Hello Word

The function file_exists() is bypassed

Source:
http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2004/Feb/82